# Did a Partial Update for 13.10

Tags: partial-upgrade

So today, my computer asked for an update and I figured yah I got time. So I did it and then it said some packages were not installed properly and would like to do a partial update.

Figured well that's fine and did it. Once I was done I rebooted and then boom a lot of stuff turned white and have alot graphical glitches and I cant see any picutures and it keeps asking for updates but I cant update it.

Not really sure what I can do about it. I just really regret doing that partial update.

I am using a ATIV Book 8 with the 64-bit Version of Ubuntu 13.10 being dual-booted with Windows 8.1 Pro.

Output of `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
dx511@ATIV:~$ sudo apt-get install -f 
[sudo] password for dx511: 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Comment: I guess you'd update from grub through terminal commands and it may get fixed but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Can you get to a tty through Ctrl+Alt+F1?

Comment: The computer still boots to the desktop it just has alot of grahpical issues. Like everything still works other then viewing pictures and the graphical issues and not being able to update. And yah I can @saiarcot895

Comment: At any rate, as a starting point, run `sudo apt-get install -f` to resolve any missing/broken dependencies.

Comment: no that didnt work @saiarcot895 :/

Comment: dx511@ATIV:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for dx511: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
dx511@ATIV:~$

Comment: I've read doing a Partial update is a bad idea. "Most 'Partial Upgrade' situations occur due to package archive inconsistencies, which will typically be resolved within a few hours." However, I did it anyways. AND NOW IM REALLY REGRETTING IT. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Partial upgrade is something that should be generally avoided**, and surely avoided when an essential package is held back.

The procedure when partial upgrade message is shown is

1. Find the packages which are been held back.(they are shown in the message.)
2. Either install them properly(a.k.a fix them) or remove them if unwanted.

Well, now that you have gone through partial upgrade, and have messed the things, I'm pretty sure a important package was held back and you removed it.OK enough of theory.

---

Try the following command, which should install all you need

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! However I fixed this by updating to 14.04 LTS. All is well again. :)

Comment: 14.04 is still in beta.You are likely to have many problems there.But as release date comes closer, the bugs would vanish.remember  to update it regularly(at least once a week).

Comment: I do update regularly. Bi-daily the latest. But thanks for the tip though!